# C Programming: String Copy Using Heap

Tags: c, memory-management

```
char* StringCopy(const char* string) {
    char* newString;
    int len;
    len = strlen(string) ;
    newString = malloc(sizeof(char)*len); 

    strcpy(newString, string); 
    return(newString); 
}
```

Above code works even though newString is local and should be deallocated at the end of the function. I am new to C, any link which explain this or explanation would be very helpful. I mean should not we get an error like this: address of stack memory associated with local
      variable 'newString' returned?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You have to manage your own heap memory in C. So, if you allocate some memory in a function and you don't de-allocate it, it stays allocated until your process terminates (or you de-allocate it elsewhere).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

newString is a local variable in the scope of the StringCopy function. It is assigned a pointer which points to the malloc'ed memory.

When we return from this function, the variable newString would be deallocated. However, the memory area allocated (in which the newString pointer points to) is not. The caller of this function would still be able to access the memory area through the returned pointer.

Note: You have to check malloc's return value because it might return NULL.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `newString` is the address of the string on heap.

Above code return the value of `newString`.

The string on heap would not be destroyed until you free() it or process exit().

Answer (score 0):

You are also overwriting the malloc'ed memory by one byte... Don't forget the null char terminator takes one; you need to add one to len